# Setting the thumb-size of each scroll-bar (horizontal and vertical)

Tags: winapi, mfc, scrollbar

I am trying to set the thumb-size of each scroll-bar (horizontal and vertical).

First I initialize a `SCROLLINFO` structure:

```
SCROLLINFO info{};
info.cbSize = sizeof(info);
info.fMask = SIF_PAGE;
```

Then I call the `SetScrollInfo` function for each scroll-bar:

```
info.nPage = m_Width;
SetScrollInfo(SB_HORZ,&info);
info.nPage = m_Height;
SetScrollInfo(SB_VERT,&info);
```

**But only the vertical scroll-bar seems to be updated.**

And if I swap the order of execution:

```
info.nPage = m_Height;
SetScrollInfo(SB_VERT,&info);
info.nPage = m_Width;
SetScrollInfo(SB_HORZ,&info);
```

**Then only the horizontal scroll-bar seems to be updated.**

Any idea what on earth is going on here?

For all it matters, I am doing all of this inside the `OnPaint` routine.

Thank you.

Comment: Er, you don't appear to be setting `info.fRedraw`. Is that intentional? I.e - you should set the flag to true to force a redraw. I'll bet the second call causes the effects of the first to become visible, but aren't in a position to test presently. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787595(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @enhzflep: No such variable in this structure.

Comment: @enhzflep: Also, it's the second call which seems to work, not the first call.

Comment: enhzflep introduces his palm to his face. Derrr! Not sure quite how I missed both of those points. :slinks-away-with-tail-between-legs:

Comment: What does happen if you use two separate `SCROLLINFO` variables, one for each scrollbar? About your scenario, without the approach I suggested: May be the var is getting altered after the first call, as you pass a memory address pointing to `SetScrollInfo` instead of a copy, which allows the function to modify its value. You can confirm there were changes been made doing a `Watch` of your `info` variable and see if the corresponding on the Watch Window line turns red when executing your first `SetScrollInfo`.

Comment: I agree with @sergiol its seems to be clear case of overwriting existing variable with next call

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade: For me it is not clear it is, it is only a suspicion I have. But debugger can confirm whether it is or not.

Comment: @sergiol: 1. There's no need to use two separate `SCROLLINFO` variables, since this argument in function `SetScrollInfo` is a **strictly-input** argument. How do I know that? Well, in the [MSDN description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787595(v=vs.85).aspx), this argument is precedes with an `_In_`.

Comment: @sergiol: 2. Nevertheless, should I choose not to "trust" MSDN (since this macro is merely a hint, which has no compile-time or run-time effect), the contents of the variable are not changed after the first call. So again, no point in using two separate variables.

Comment: @sergiol: 3. It's **the first call** to function `SetScrollInfo` which seems to make no impact. Had it been the second call, one might have correctly deduce your conclusion, that possibly the `SCROLLINFO` variable has changed, leading function `SetScrollInfo` to fail the second time it is called. So in short, this is not the issue. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: You are looking to the wrong documentation. You would want to look at the documentation of [`CWnd::SetScrollInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h265xads(v=vs.120).aspx) method and not to `::SetScrollInfo` global function.

Answer (score 0):

You should only set the page size from the WM_SIZE handler, and of course, when your virtual space size changes.